# How to map data mapping in Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Take the following example from [Angular's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource):

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
  {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
   charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
  });

 // We can retrieve a collection from the server
 var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
   // GET: /user/123/card
   // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];
```

What is the correct way to map the data structure, an onject with 3 properties in this example, that returns from the server, without the need to "guess" the structure. see the comment "// server returns.. "  - I don't want to assume that, but to have a more structural way, like an expected interface or something alike.

**How do you map data in angular than ?**

Comment: Not following what you mean. Doesn't $resource automatically map the results (e.g cards.name == 'Smith', cards.id == '456', etc.)?

Comment: I mean that on the client side, you have to 'guess' how wil the Json will look like, e.g. Obj.Name or Obj.Date.  Now, what if the server sends you a Json that doesn't match what you were hopping for? I was hoping for a way to create an interface between client & server, that will tell tham both about the model format

Comment: That would mean making two models both on the server and the client. My thought is you should create your model on the server and deliver it to the client. What the server delivers in JSON is the object model. Not?

Comment: Let's say someone changes the server's model, and now it sends a JSON that has property name x instead of X. The client will fail in runt time. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Aside from the obvious/horrible approach of using a large amount of if/else statements, what environment are you working in where you're unsure what structure the data will have when it is delivered from the server?? It's usually either A: You own the server/data and can control what the model looks like or B: The server is some sort of JSON API that is properly versioned and stable

Comment: I'm in version A, but we are a global team so once one programmer changed the server's interface, my client will fail in run time (instead of compile time)

Comment: A suggestion is to focus your resources on ensuring API errors aren't made in production and that any changes to it also involve client testing. Even if you could prevent some issues based on field names or whatnot, you're only mitigating the risk somewhat. You're better off spending your resources on establishing a sound deployment workflow. Furthermore, I don't know of anything in Angular that is going to help you achieve what you're looking to do.